# Value error dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python, django, backend

I want to write a context processor, so that the list can be seen anywhere in the application in django (version 2.1).
I'm getting an error:

```
ValueError at /

dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

```
def following_issues(request):
    request_context = RequestContext(request)
    request_context.push({'following_issues': Issue.objects.filter(followers=request.user.is_authenticated)})
    return request_context
```

In my settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'base.context_processors.following_issues',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how to write a context processor. As the [documentation [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) says:

> A context processor has a very simple interface: It's a **Python function that takes one argument**, an `HttpRequest` object, and **returns a dictionary** that gets added to the template context. Each context processor must return a dictionary.

So you should simply write this as:

```
def following_issues(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return {
            'following_topics': Issue.objects.filter(followers=request.user)
        }
    else:
        return {
            'following_topics': Issue.objects.none()
        }
```

We thus can simply return a dictionary here where we map `following_topics` on `Issue.objects.filter(..)` expression.

Furthermore you can not specify `followers=request.user.is_authenticated`, since that is a boolean, and you probably, given I understand the modeling correctly, filter on the user. Here I wrote that in case the user is not authenticated, we return an empty `QuerySet`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now in template where I have ```{{ following_topics }}``` - return empty list, but I have some data there.

Comment: @user10605113: there was a problem with your query as well, you wrote `followers=request.user.is_authenticated`. I fixed that now. Does this help?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot :) +1